# "div" into an "a" is wrong. So, how can I do this? (HTML4, CSS2, crossbrowser)

Tags: html, css

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p8Mps/2/) code :

## HTML

```
<div class="temperatura">
    <a href="/link/" class="temperatura_localita">
        <div style="padding-left:12px;">
            Text1
        </div>
    </a>
    
    <a href="/link/" class="temperatura_dettagli">
        <div style="padding-right:70px;">            
            Text2
        </div>
    </a>        
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.temperatura
{
    height:34px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#FF0000;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.temperatura_localita
{
    width:50%;
    height:34px;
    line-height:34px;
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.temperatura_dettagli
{
    width:50%;
    height:34px;
    line-height:34px;
    float:left;
    text-align:right;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

I need two linkable element (50% each) with a padding left(first) and right(the second).

The only strategy I know is to make two `a` (floatted) with internal divs with padding.

But it is "incorrect". So how can I do this?

**EDIT**

The other solution is just change the internal div (the ones with padding) with span : http://jsfiddle.net/p8Mps/3/

But try to enlarge/decrease the window on IE7 : it will fails...

Comment: Why is it "incorrect"? Afaik, `<a>` can only contain inline elements, no block level elements. Thus, `a div` (speaking css) is "incorrect" (per DTD)

Comment: @knittl: [the `a` element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-a-element.html#the-a-element) has a [transparent content model](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/content-models.html#transparent), meaning that it can contain anything which its parent can contain, including block level elements.

Comment: @Sidnicious: maybe in HTML5 (is it final yet?). I was actually talking about HTML4 (haven't mentioned it though)

Comment: @markzzz Why don't you just define the padding on the anchor elements themselves?

Comment: Love watching conversations about the differences between HTML4 and HTML5 that make no mention of each version.

Comment: @Sidnicious:  [HTML 4.01 specifications state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A) that `<a>` elements may only contain inline elements. A `<div>` is a block level element, so it must not appear inside an `<a>`.

Comment: You cannot add padding to the a elements 50% : it will also take the padding space, and it will create a new line. I supposed this was clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a>` (anchors) are inline elements.

`<div>` (divisions) are block level elements.

[HTML 4.01 specifications state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A) that `<a>` elements may only contain inline elements. A `<div>` is a block level element, so it must not appear inside an `<a>`.

Never put block level elements inside inline elements.

You would put inline elements inside block level elements instead...

```
<div class="temperatura">
    <div style="padding-left:12px;">
        <a href="/link/" class="temperatura_localita">
            Text1
       </a>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-right:70px;">
        <a href="/link/" class="temperatura_dettagli">      
            Text2
        </a> 
    </div>       
</div>
```

**EDIT** based on OP's comments...

http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/p8Mps/9/

```
<div class="temperatura">
    <div class="temperatura_localita">
        <a href="/link/" style="margin-left:12px;">
            Text1
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="temperatura_dettagli">
        <a href="/link/" style="margin-right:70px;">      
            Text2
        </a> 
    </div>       
</div>
```

**EDIT 2** based on further comments...

http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/p8Mps/13/

```
<div class="temperatura">
    <a href="/link1/" class="temperatura_localita">
        <span>Text1</span>
    </a>

    <a href="/link2/" class="temperatura_dettagli"> 
        <span>Text2</span>
    </a>   
</div>
```

Comment: ?? I need them inline. I need 50% both: adding a padding to the a href will put in two line the a elements.

Comment: I'm embarassed :O Why your example works? Its strange. In fact, putting margin on css stylesheet fails http://jsfiddle.net/p8Mps/6/ . What's happening?

Comment: @markzzz, why not use margins instead of padding?  Then leave the inner `div`'s at `50%` each and put the margins on the `<a>` tags.  See edited answer & fiddle...   http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/p8Mps/8/

Comment: @markzzz, it's failing because now you're putting the margin on the class applied to the `div`.  In my example, the margin was applied to the `<a>`.

Comment: Oh ok. Now I see. Anyway, the last option have another behaviour : the whole container (div) in fact is not "linked" as my example.

Comment: @markzzz, See my updated fiddle, [putting the margin style within the CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/p8Mps/9).  Typically, you don't see entire containers (block level) as clickable links by wrapping them with an anchor tag... you'd use JavaScript to bind an `onclick` event to the whole container.  In menu systems where you see something similar, it's because an image is wrapped with an anchor which is ok because an image is inline.

Comment: Is not what I'm looking for Sparky672 : `temperatura` must be linkable...the whole "container" :)

Comment: @markzzz, This seems to work as you desire... http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/p8Mps/13

Comment: NO! :) Try to run it on IE7 and increase-decrease the window : it fails. I've also opened a discussion about this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918536/why-these-span-inside-an-a-fail-using-ie7/7918732#7918732

Comment: @markzzz, please do not post duplicate questions.  One will likely be closed.

Answer (score 2):

I would make the 'a' tags

```
display: block;
```

That will give you the ability to style them as if they were div tags and you can add the padding left and padding right accordingly.

Comment: yeah, I can also style these as I want, becuase they are `float:left;`

Answer (score 1):

Take knittl's comment into consideration.
I can think of 2 possible solutions:

1)Use only the `div`'s (without the `a` tags), and use the `onclick` attribute to redirect to your desired url.

2) Add `display:block` to the `a` css and omit the `div`'s. Then style tha a tags as desired

Comment: No. You cannot put div into an a element. Is wrong. Firefox maybe can correct this error, but IE won't do it. Also, I will avoid javascript...

Comment: Soluton 1 gets a "F" in accessibility (how would users navigating via keyboard, much less screenreader users access those links?)

Comment: That's what i said, use either `a` or `div`, not `div` in `a`.
Anyway, i think it's not too complicated, if you play around with it you'll manage to do what you want ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a container to add padding to an anchor. So, use:

```
<div class="temperatura">
    <a href="/link/" class="temperatura_localita" style="padding-left:12px;">
        Text1
    </a>

    <a href="/link/" class="temperatura_dettagli" style="padding-right:70px;">            
        Text2
    </a>        
</div>
```

If you **really** need a container, change `div` to `span`, and add `display:block` to the span element. After this declaration, the `<span>` element will "behave" similar to the `<div>` element.

Comment: I see that I just use <span style="padding-left:12px;"> instead of div : it gets the padding. But on IE7, 50% on padded span sometimes sucks...

Comment: Check my EDIT on the question. You don't need display:block for internal span, but fail on IE7 on scrolling...

Comment: @markzzz Another method is to usespecific `display` properties, **see http://jsfiddle.net/p8Mps/7/**