# Why these "span" inside an "a" fail using IE7?

Tags: html, css

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p8Mps/10/) code :

## HTML (meaning 4.0)

```
<div class="temperatura">
    <a href="/link/" class="temperatura_localita">
        <span style="padding-left:12px;">
            Text1
        </span>
    </a>
    
    <a href="/link/" class="temperatura_dettagli">
        <span style="padding-right:70px;">            
            Text2
        </span>
    </a>        
</div>
```

## CSS (meaning 2)

```
.temperatura
{
    height:34px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#FF0000;
}

.temperatura_localita
{
    width:50%;
    height:34px;
    line-height:34px;
    float:left;
}

.temperatura_dettagli
{
    width:50%;
    height:34px;
    line-height:34px;
    float:left;
    text-align:right;
}
```

and this is what I need :

- the container `temperatura` is linked to `/link/`;
- each `a` are 50%, and the link got a padding (left or right);

on Firefox/Chrome/IE8/IE9 there arent problem. On IE7, increasing/deacresing (horizontal) the window, the second link got a new line.

Why? And, how can I fix this?

Comment: If you remove the `width: 50%` attribute from both link elements, do they render on the same line?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["div" into an "a" is wrong. So, how can I do this? (HTML4, CSS2, crossbrowser)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917684/div-into-an-a-is-wrong-so-how-can-i-do-this-html4-css2-crossbrowser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because of your 50%/50% division.  IE7 is pushing the second link to a new line when the pixel count of the div is odd, but maintaining the correct position when it's even.  Changing both widths to 49% solves the issue.